# get the room by id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on a hotel Reservation Project in MVC 3
Here I display the rooms:
[image]

When i click to reserve a romm i get here :

[image]

But what i want to do is  to get the number of the room i  selected directly in the Reservation form room box.

Here is my  Create view for reservation:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Reservation</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Room_ID, "Room")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Room_ID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Room_ID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Guest_ID, "Client")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Guest_ID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Guest_ID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Data_Check_in)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data_Check_in)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Data_Check_in)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Data_Check_out)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data_Check_out)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Data_Check_out)
    </div>



    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Preference_ID, "Preferinte")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Preference_ID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Preference_ID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Card_ID, "Card_de_credit")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Card_ID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Card_ID)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Can you pass the room id from the first page to the form page using a view model?